# How to split a content of a exisiting arrary element in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

The code looks like this

```
txt = "ID:2020,Sugar:3,cost_sugar:30,ID:2021,Sugar:5,cost_sugar:50"
x = str(txt.split(","))
```

And the output is

```
['ID:2020', 'Sugar:3']
```

Now I want to perform split again such that the output should look like:

```
['ID', '2020', 'Sugar', '3']
```

Comment: Please post an MCVE. The code you show here is not doing what you say it does.

Comment: please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the answers provided by people by using the `re` module. Here is another way to do that:

```py
txt.replace(":", ",").split(",")
```

Essentially, you're treating `":"` as a `","`, so why not first replace the `":"` with a `","` and then split?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(",|:", txt)
['ID', '2020', 'Sugar', '3', 'cost_sugar', '30', 'ID', '2021', 'Sugar', '5', 'cost_sugar', '50']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `re` module has a nice feature

```
import re
re.split(':|,',txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either code below related with your project, or it's a good example if you are learning the first time. The first one uses list. The second one uses `re`.

```
txt = "ID:2020,Sugar:3,cost_sugar:30,ID:2021,Sugar:5,cost_sugar:50"
returnlist = []
for x in list(txt.split(",")):
  for fullkey in list(x.split(":")):
    returnlist.append(fullkey)

print(returnlist)
```

OR

```
import re
txt = "ID:2020,Sugar:3,cost_sugar:30,ID:2021,Sugar:5,cost_sugar:50"
returnlist = re.split(':|,', txt)
print(returnlist)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use a list to first get the key and values and then print the list

Comment: Without an example, this isn't saying anything useful